# Can't get data from GetJson method

Tags: c#, asp.net, jstree

Here is my code in Default.aspx:

```
$(function() {
        var dataSource = {};
        $("#MainTree,#SubTree").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax":{
                    type: "POST",
                    async: true,
                    url: "Default.aspx/GetJson",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(msg) {
                        dataSource = msg;
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    },
                    data: dataSource,
                },
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "dnd"]
        });
    });
```

And here is GetJson method in Default.aspx.cs:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetJson()
{
    System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
    Dictionary<string, object> row = null;

    DataTable dtEmployee = new DataTable();

    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("EmpId", typeof(int));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Address", typeof(string));
    dtEmployee.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));

    //
    // Here we add five DataRows.
    //
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(25, "Rk", "Gurgaon", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(50, "Sachin", "Noida", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(10, "Nitin", "Noida", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(21, "Aditya", "Meerut", DateTime.Now);
    dtEmployee.Rows.Add(100, "Mohan", "Banglore", DateTime.Now);

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtEmployee.Rows)
    {
        row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        foreach (DataColumn col in dtEmployee.Columns)
        {
            row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
        }
        rows.Add(row);
    }
    return serializer.Serialize(rows);
}
```

EDIT:
This is the result when i check GetJson method respone:
   {"d":"[{\"EmpId\":25,\"Name\":\"Rk\",\"Address\":\"Gurgaon\",\"Date\":\"\/Date(1372999726975)\/\"},{\"EmpId\":50,\"Name\":\"Sachin\",\"Address\":\"Noida\",\"Date\":\"\/Date(1372999726975)\/\"},{\"EmpId\":10,\"Name\":\"Nitin\",\"Address\":\"Noida\",\"Date\":\"\/Date(1372999726975)\/\"},{\"EmpId\":21,\"Name\":\"Aditya\",\"Address\":\"Meerut\",\"Date\":\"\/Date(1372999726975)\/\"},{\"EmpId\":100,\"Name\":\"Mohan\",\"Address\":\"Banglore\",\"Date\":\"\/Date(1372999726975)\/\"}]"}

And the result is nothing..It just appeared "..Loading" flashly and then it return blank page..please help me to show what's the problem here is..Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you've not read the documentation properly so I would suggest you do that first.

When you use **json_data** plugin, you need to follow basic structure as shown below and could be found [here](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/json_data), that means you need to provide Json data in below format:

```
{ 
    "data" : "node_title", 
    // omit `attr` if not needed; the `attr` object gets passed to the jQuery `attr` function
    "attr" : { "id" : "node_identificator", "some-other-attribute" : "attribute_value" }, 
    // `state` and `children` are only used for NON-leaf nodes
    "state" : "closed", // or "open", defaults to "closed"
    "children" : [ /* an array of child nodes objects */ ]
}
```

Taking response structure into consideration, you need to have server side class as shown below:

```
public class Emp
{
    public EmpAttribute attr { get; set; }
    public string data { get; set; }

}
public class EmpAttribute
{
    public string id;
    public bool selected;
}
```

And your pagemethod should look alike below:

```
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static List<Emp> GetJson()
    {
        List<Emp> empTreeArray = new List<Emp>();

        Emp emp1 = new Emp()
        {
            attr = new EmpAttribute(){ id= "25",selected=false},
            data = "Nitin-Gurgaon"
        };

        Emp emp2 = new Emp()
        {
            attr =  new EmpAttribute(){ id="50",selected=false},
            data = "Sachin-Noida"
        };
        empTreeArray.Add(emp1);
        empTreeArray.Add(emp2);
        return empTreeArray;
    }
```

Your clientside binding code should be like below:

```
$(function() {
        var dataSource = {};
        $("#demo1").jstree({
            "json_data": {
                "ajax":{
                    "type": "POST",
                    "url": "Default2.aspx/GetJson",
                    "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    "dataType": "json",
                    success: function(msg) {
                        return msg.d;
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        alert(err);
                    }                   
                }
            },
            "plugins": ["themes", "json_data", "ui", "dnd"]
        });
    });
```

Notice **return msg.d** in Success function that is missing from your code.

More examples could be found [here](http://simpledotnetsolutions.wordpress.com/2012/11/25/jstree-few-examples-with-asp-netc/)

Please go through documentation of any plugin you use next time.

Answer (score 0):

type http://Default.aspx/GetJson  directly in browser and check whether correct data is coming or not.

Other two locations where you can add debugging code is

```
                success: function(msg) {
                    dataSource = msg;
                },
                error: function(err) {
                    alert(err);
                }
```

add breakpoints and debug the javascript.

Comment: please see my edit above..I don't know why I can't debug at 2 breakpoints you show me..perhaps it steps through those points..

Answer (score 0):

The response is encapsulated in a property called "d". Instead of `datasource = msg` you should have `datasource = msg.d`

Comment: yup..I have changed it..and it still got nothing..like what had happened before